# Having issues with linking Github repository to Bamboo

Tags: git, github, bamboo

Having issues with linking Github repository to Bamboo.
Version of git I have is 1.7.1.

And the error I see in the logs is:

> com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.git.GitCommandException: command /usr/bin/git ls-remote https://rreddy:********@github.com/xxxx/test.git failed with code 128. Working directory was [.]., stderr:
>
> error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://rreddy:********@github.com/xxx/test.git/info/refs

Credentials I passed where correct as I see it working on my local.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue on Bamboo 5.9.4. For one it seems Bamboo cannot cope with special characters in the password. I had a ")" in the password and replaced it with "#".
Still i get authentication problems, while it works with the same user and pwd from the command line.

Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced these kind of git issues in bamboo while using old git versions.Can you upgrade your git version up to 1.9.0 or higher.

NOTE:
Make sure to install new git version in /usr/bin/ path.Otherwise bamboo will not able to find the latest git version.